# How do I declare a PHP var from a post type for a for loop when using Timber for WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, var, timber

I am currently getting an undefined variable error returned in php using twig/timber declarations on WordPress and even though the code below returns and displays the posts on the page as intended, I am still receiving the error message in debug mode (See below). I realise PHP vars need to be declared and that I am not declaring $jobs anywhere before the loop, but my understanding is that $context converts the post type 'jobs' into a php var. If not what am I doing wrong and how to I declare it?

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: jobs in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxx.co.uk/wp-content/themes/xxxx/front-page.php on line 19
```

PHP file:

```
$context['jobs'] = Timber::get_posts('post_type=jobs&posts_per_page=3');

if(is_array($jobs)){ /* line 19 */
    // Closing date display format (e.g. 24th October 2019)
    foreach( $jobs as &$job ){
        $job->job_close_date_formatted = date( 'jS F Y', strtotime( $job->job_close_date ) );
    }
}
$context['options'] = get_fields('acf-theme-options');
```

TWIG file:

```
            {% for job in jobs %}
                {% include 'components/home-job-panel.twig' %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `$context['jobs']` and `$jobs` are not the same, it needs to be `if(is_array($context['jobs']))` and your loop needs to be `$context['jobs'] as $job`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jobs` are being displayed because u've defined them in `$context`

```
$context['jobs'] = Timber::get_posts('post_type=jobs&posts_per_page=3');
```

The `foreach` you are doing now has no impact on any of the jobs as `$jobs`is indeed undefined. If you wanted to modify some data you would need to use the following `foreach`

```
if (is_array($context['jobs'])) foreach($context['jobs'] as &$job) {
```

---

I wouldn't actually bother with transforming data inside your controller. Imho that is the purpose of filters inside `twig`/`timber`

```
{% for job in jobs %}
    {{ job.job_close_date | date('jS F Y') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :) I did exactly what you said and let twig deal with transforming the data and that fixed it.